# Set AUTOINCREMENT value in django table

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have the following table in mysql:

```
CREATE TABLE `portal_asset` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `asset_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1000000 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

How would I create thie same table in django? So far I have the following, but not sure how to set the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value --

```
class PortalAsset(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    asset_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'portal_asset'
```

How can I set the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value to start off at 1000000 ? The equivalent of:

```
alter table portal_asset AUTO_INCREMENT=1000000;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a [`RunSQL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/migration-operations/#runsql) operation in your migrations to execute the necessary SQL:

```
migrations.RunSQL("ALTER TABLE portal_asset AUTO_INCREMENT=1000000;")
```

If you haven't run any migrations, you can add this to your first migration to ensure no rows are inserted before the new value is set. Otherwise you'll have to add this operation in a new migration. You can create a new, empty migration using `python manage.py makemigrations --empty <yourappname>`.