# How to set Django model IntegerField as a primary and to start at 100, also be Auto Increment?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

How to set model field that starts at integer 100 and auto increment as well as it needs to be a primary key. here is my models.py file

```
from django.db import models
class URLShortner(models.Model):

    # that integerfield here
    original_url = models.CharField()
    shortned_url = models.CharField()

    def __str__(self):
         return self.original_url
```

Also, a ModelForm which only accepts original_url and auto assign to integerfield. Please help me. :)

Comment: Why do you care what number it starts at?

Comment: I have an algorithm which works if the value of an integer is more than 128. So I want it to start from 100.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot do directly,you need run manual sql query like that

```
ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 100;
```

after running migrations,do above sql query in your database,

another option also is there check this post [Mirgations RunSql](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34279889/7261317)